# Choropleth in Folium - having issues

Tags: choropleth, folium

I am quite new to coding and need to create some type of map to display my data.
I have data in an excel sheet showing a list of countries and a number showing amount of certain crimes. I want to show this in a choropleth map.

I have seen lots of different ways to code this but can't seem to get any to correctly read in the data. Will I need to get import country codes into my df?

I have my world map from github and downloaded it in its raw format to my computer and into jupyter notebook.

My dataframe is also loaded, as the excel sheet, in jupyter notebook.

What are the first steps i need to take to load this into a map?

This is the code I have had the most success with:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium

df = pd.read_excel('UK - Nationality and Type.xlsx')
state_geo = 'countries.json'

m1 = folium.Map(location=[55, 4], zoom_start=3)
m1.choropleth(
geo_data=state_geo,
data=df,
columns=['Claimed Nationality', 'Labour Exploitation'],
key_on='feature.id',
fill_color='YlGn',
fill_opacity=0.5,
line_opacity=0.2,
legend_name='h',
highlight=True
)

m1.save("my_map.html")`
```

But i just get a big world map, all in the same shade of grey

[this is what the countries.json looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAzlC.png)

Comment: Hey Sam, what version of folium do you have?  Also any chance you could post an excerpt of `countries.json`?  or perhaps a link to it?

Comment: `columns=['Claimed Nationality', 'Labour Exploitation'],`
`key_on='feature.id',` do the 'Claimed Nationality' and 'feature.id's match? They should.

Comment: i am unsure which version is running - it is preloaded on my university system

Comment: I have now fixed the key on code to ensure  this matches the json and I have a coloured map now which seems correct - is there a way to add hover markers showing the specific number in relation to that country?

Comment: also before doing markers - it appears that country data that doesnt appear in my df but is in the json file is coloured rather than remaining blank - is there a way to only show the countries shown in my df?

Comment: Check here for options on choropleth documentation [link](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#module-folium.features) It looks like you could add `nan_fill_color = 'white'` to make the unlisted countries white.

Comment: this is what i get when i add the nan foll color in: TypeError: choropleth() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nan_fill_color'

Comment: Hi Sam, then your folium version is probably too old. You can check your version by doing `print(folium.__version__)` after importing folium of course.

Comment: thank you! it is now all working with the new install of folium :)

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I have a similar problem. Can you help me out? Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563700/choropleth-map-is-not-showing-color-variation-in-the-output

Comment: I started using azure notebook instead of anaconda - my system at Uni still had an old version of colour installed but azure allowed me to install the latest version of folium